# Why do i get this error in registering?

Tags: python

[image]

Why do i get this error while registering?
as shown in image:

This is my node tree:

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import NodeTree, Node, NodeSocket, Menu, Panel, Operator, PropertyGroup
from bpy.props import FloatProperty, IntProperty, BoolProperty, StringProperty, PointerProperty
import nodeitems_utils
from nodeitems_utils import NodeCategory, NodeItem

class FLARENODETREE(NodeTree):
    bl_label = "ProFlareGen"
    bl_idname = 'main.node_tree'
    bl_icon = 'NODETREE'

# Custom socket type
class NodeSocket(NodeSocket):
    bl_label = "Socket"
    bl_idname = 'flare.main_socket'

    # Enum items list
    my_items = (
        ('DOWN', "Down", "Where your feet are"),
        ('UP', "Up", "Where your head should be"),
        ('LEFT', "Left", "Not right"),
        ('RIGHT', "Right", "Not left"),
    )

    my_enum_prop: bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="Direction",
        description="Just an example",
        items=my_items,
        default='UP',
    )

    # Optional function for drawing the socket input value
    def draw(self, context, layout, node, text):
        if self.is_output or self.is_linked:
            layout.label(text=text)
        else:
            layout.prop(self, "my_enum_prop", text=text)

    # Socket color
    def draw_color(self, context, node):
        return (1.0, 0.4, 0.216, 0.5)
```

This is the class that have the error:

```
class FLARENODETREENODE:
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, ntree):
        return ntree.bl_idname == 'main.node_tree'
```

Comment: Which class does it fail at registering? How is that class defined?

Comment: this class ```class FLARENODETREENODE:
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, ntree):
        return ntree.bl_idname == 'main.node_tree'```

Comment: Suggest to add *how* you register the class to re-open the q (since this is your q here obviously).

Comment: The class needs to be a subclass of a Blender class. [Doc](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.utils.html?highlight=register_class#bpy.utils.register_class)

Comment: @scurest I don't get it. What do need to do?